# how to create more then one thread at a time

Tags: c++, multithreading

Can anyone tell me how to create more then one thread at a time
is there any such ?
like:
pthread_create (thread, attr, start_routine, arg) 
should give me more than one thread at a time.

Comment: Just call `pthread_create` as many times as you need threads.

Comment: Why do you want that?

Comment: I want one or more threads to access one function at a time.so that i get an error

Comment: If accessing a function multiple times is a problem, something is wrong with this function.

Comment: What kind of error do you expect from that? Please give us the whole story, as what you said until now doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Hmmm...OK.I should write a testcase where i should create some threads and make those threads to call one function. if more then one thread tries to access that function at a time, it should crash or should create some problem. to create that scenario i want to know to how to make two threads to access same function at a time

Comment: @ deviantfan.yes. I have fixed that problem in function using mutex. but i want to produce the fault through tests

Comment: @user3913114 I don´t understand why anyone really *want* to make such bugs, but: a) Get rid of that mutex again, because it will prevent such bugs (usually a good thing, but in your case...). And with an usual OS, you can´t just say "I wan´t this two threads to access it on the same time, now". You could try to execute this function many times, like 1 million etc., and with a bit of luck some if the accessess will not work correctly. (however, this doesn´t mean they will crash immediately. There are many kinds of potential problems).

Answer (score 1):

Your actual question seems to be more like "How can I make sure my tests exercise a potential race condition by calling the same function at the exact same time?"

The answer is, you sort of can't.  Imagine your test runs on a single-processor machine.  There's no way for the function to be called twice at the same time (but it could partially execute once then start again in the other thread).

Think about other ways to test for race conditions.  At the more formal end of the spectrum, you can use tools like Spin and Promela to verify such things, but it's a lot more involved than spawning two threads in a unit test.  For more, see here: http://lwn.net/Articles/243851/

A less formal way is to call your function in some way where it will sleep in its middle when the first thread calls it.  Then you're very likely to see execution continue with the second call while the first one is suspended.  But be mindful of wasting time on this approach, because it mostly validates that you've written the test correctly, and may not prove anything much about the thread safety of your code in practice.